# Fitting 3 spans in a single div, works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So I have a issue with some CSS styling that works in Chrome but not in FireFox.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vw4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner frozenColumn head" column-id="a149a4ba-c0a6-4d7f-a420-b55b65ef3003" draggable="true">
    <span>Cluster1</span>
    <span class="resizeColumn">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="sort arrow-up"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.head {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
div.frozenColumn {
    border-right: 1px double #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
}
div.inner {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
    height: 28px;
}
div {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.resizeColumn {
    background-color: gray;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 3px;
}


.arrow-up {
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    float: right;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 0;
}
```

Essentially the one in Chrome shows the arrow and the re-size column div as intended but FireFox does not.

Any idea why the difference between the browsers is occurring?

Comment: The requirement is there for a reason. Please post the code

Comment: HTML and CSS are considered *code* for this matter. They should be included, if you link to a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove **white-space: nowrap;** css form your code and u can see arrow and second span in firefox.

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6vw4/1/)

```
div.head {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
div.frozenColumn {
    border-right: 1px double #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
div.inner {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
    height: 28px;
}
div {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.resizeColumn {
    background-color: gray;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 3px;
}


.arrow-up {
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    float: right;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 0;
}
```